# SQL Server, Count Consecutive Weeks Record Has Been in Top 5

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have this complicated query:

```
SELECT rs.Name, rs.sumhits, rs.weeknumber from(
    SELECT Name, weeknumber, sum(hits) as sumhits, Rank()
    over (Partition By weeknumber ORDER BY sum(hits) desc) AS Rank
FROM
(
    SELECT
    Name,
    DATEDIFF
    (
        day,
        (SELECT DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,(select min(Table2.date) from Table2)), 0)),
        (Table2.date)
    ) / 7 as weeknumber,
    hits
    FROM Table1
    INNER JOIN Table2 on Table1.nameId = Name.Id
) as a
GROUP BY
Name,
weeknumber
)
rs where rank <= 5
order by weeknumber desc
```

which provides me with the top five "names" with the most "hits" for each week.

I would like to add to this another field that calculates the number of consecutive weeks each name in this week's top five has been in the top five. So, another column that would have a value of 1 if a name in this week's top five was not in last week's, a value of 3 if a name from this week's top five had also been in the top five the previous two weeks, etc.

What would be the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Your query is a real mess.  I would suggest that you add sample data and desired results.

Comment: I tried to describe the desired results. I guess "this week's" could be unclear. I meant the top five for the greatest (or top 1) "weeknumber".

Answer (score 0):

You could think of your query as a CTE and add further information in follow-up CTEs or the final SELECT:

Something like this:

```
WITH myCTE AS
(
Your Query here!!!
)
SELECT *, furtherData
FROM myCTE
```

But - as was commented already - your query seems to be "enhanceable" :-) Maybe you post sample data and expected result...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, your base data is the following:

```
SELECT Name, dateadd(day, 1 - datepart(dow, date), date) as weekstart,
       sum(hits) as numhits,
       rank() over (partition by dateadd(day, 1 - datepart(dow, date), date)
                    order by sum(hits) desc) as ranking,
       (case when rank() over (partition by dateadd(day, 1 - datepart(dow, date), date)
                    order by sum(hits) desc) <= 5
              then 1 else 0 end) as Top5
FROM Table1 INNER JOIN
     Table2
     on Table1.nameId = Name.Id
GROUP BY Name, dateadd(day, 1 - datepart(dow, date), date);
```

This gives hits by week, along with the ranking.  Now we can ask the question of the number of consecutive weeks in the top 5.

```
with cte as (
      SELECT Name, dateadd(day, 1 - datepart(dow, date), date) as weekstart,
             sum(hits) as hits,
             rank() over (partition by dateadd(day, 1 - datepart(dow, date), date)
                          order by sum(hits) desc) as ranking
      FROM Table1 INNER JOIN
           Table2
           on Table1.nameId = Name.Id
      GROUP BY Name, dateadd(day, 1 - datepart(dow, date), date)
     )
select cte.name, cte.numhits,
       ranking,
       (case when ranking <= 5 then Num5s else 0 end) as Num5s
from (select t.*,
             count(*) over (partition by name, grp
                            order by weekstart) as Num5s
      from (select cte.*,
                   (row_number() over (partition by name order by weekstart) -
                    row_number() over (partition by name, top5 order by weekstart)
                   ) as grp
            from cte 
           ) t
     ) t;
```

The logic is rather complicated.  The innermost subquery defines a group for each name where `grp` specifies constant values for periods when the name is in the top 5 and when it is not.  The middle subquery enumerates those values and the outer just does some logic to return the right information for top5s.

This query is untested, but if you set up a SQL Fiddle with some data, I can test it.